# The jerk that happens when going from linear to circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, jerk

Im trying to calculate the force applied to the end of a beam when going from a linear motion to a circular motion.

I have a tractor with a beam of each side with a length "L"
The tractor is moving with a constant velocity v

the tractor makes a turn and enters circular motion with a radius of R. The tractor keeps it veloicity of v, lets call it v_tractor

The end of the beam had in the linear movement a velocity of v. But as soon as the tractor does a circular move that increases its speed to v_beam. This is i calculate like this.

V_tractor/R_tractor=w (angular velocity)
w*L=v_beam

I want to find the force excerted on the end of a beam, and there must be a force as there is a change in speed from v to v_beam.
In trying to calcualte the acceleration

a=(V_beam-V)/t

but i dont know how to find t

i hope you can help me find the force excerted at the end of the beam, Just the tangential force at the end of the beam

[image]

Comment: Are you interested in the jerk, the force (torque) or the acceleration? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: i want the force excerted at the end of the beam when the tractor goes into rotation

Comment: From the title, I thought you meant centripetal (radial) jerk, like when you toss your car passengers when drifting, but your question focuses on the linear jerk because the speed of the beam doubles (for large L) during the turn. You're going to need to estimate $t$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no force exerted at the end of the beam by anything outside the beam. Each  segement of the  is acted on by the   stress forces from   the parts of the beam to the right and left of it, and the difference of the [shear  stresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_stress#Beam_shear) accelerates the segemnt while  the [bending moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bending_moment) rotates that segement. The stress  forces must go to *zero* at the ends, or else the last  infinitesimal  segment would have a finite force on it and would accelerate infinitely fast.